# Oversampling Using SMOTE Removes a Label Category from y_train

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis, oversampling, smote

I'm using LSTM for Sentiment Analysis by using imbalanced dataset having 86% positive class and 14% negative class samples. It's a very small dataset with 472 sentences but they're in regional language. Train_test_split ratio is 0.3.
I'm having two issues in implementation:

**1:** Training and Validation accuracy is constant throughout the process (Without SMOTE).
**2:** While using SMOTE for oversampling, y_train shows only 1 label in oversampled y_train.shape

```python
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

ros = SMOTE()

X_train_oversample, y_train_oversample = ros.fit_sample(X_train_pad, y_train)

print(X_train_pad.shape)
print(X_train_oversample.shape)

print(y_train.shape)
print(y_train_oversample.shape)
```

The results for y_train:

```
X_train_pad.shape                   (331, 832)
X_train_oversample.shape            (570, 832)
y_train.shape                       (331, **2**)
y_train_oversample.shape            (570, **1**)
```

However, the actual shape of data is as follows:

```
Shape of X_train_pad tensor (331, 832)
Shape of y_train tensor (331, 2)
Shape of X_test_pad tensor (141, 832)
Shape of y_test tensor (141, 2)
```

Hence, LSTM training gives error message

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Answer (score 1):

The output from SMOTE, `y_train_oversample` is not one-hot-encoded as your original `y` so you have to one-hot-encode it. You could probably figure this out if you have taken a look at the values in `y_train_oversample`.

You can do the one hot encoding using the following assuming it's an numpy array.

```py
y_train_oversample = np.eye(2)[y_train_oversample.flatten()]
```

Note that I had flatten there because if the input `y` is a matrix, the output is going to be `(n_row, 1)` and if you directly one hot encode it, you will have some dimensionality issue, so it's batter to flatten it first.

Comment: Thank you so much @TYZ. The solution worked. Another issue I'm facing is that training and validation accuracy remains same for all epochs and its 50%. How to increase it?

Comment: @ErumKazi This question is too specific and closely related to the data you have. I don't have an answer for it and it should not be dealt with here. The best is to go to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ and ask such questions.